# How do i do for Webkit on edge?

Tags: css

I have this CSS that works on chrome but not on Microsoft Edge, what can I do for it to work or are there more elements that I need to add so that it works for both browsers?

```
.a{
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 3px;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
  }
```

Comment: Ref: http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-stroke Note for Edge 15 it mentions an -ms- prefix. I don't have Edge to test.

Answer (score 0):

Really simple: you can't. Webkit and the engine for Edge don't take the same instructions

I would suggest looking at this article from CSS-tricks to emulate the effect: https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/.